# date conversion not work with my system date time

Tags: c#, .net

My system date is in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format and my code converts the date into the `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Now I want the date in the `yyyy/mm/dd` format for updating in a table in a database. I am trying with:

```
string d = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

but it returns: `yyyy/dd/mm`.

Comment: You should use `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: Could you please show a [mcve]? i.e. code that I can copy, paste, and run that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: What is the value of FromDate ?

Comment: Rather than fiddling around with *strings*, get the data into `DateTime` variables and *keep using* such variables from that point forward. Presuming SQL Server, use the appropriate datetime datatypes there, rely on ADO.Net to do the translation of these values. Just **avoid** strings, and you won't have to think about "formats".

Comment: value in FromDate = 10/07/2016 i.i dd/mm/yyyy format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert to DateTime using the original format, and then convert it to your desired format. Like this:

```
string FromDate = "12/13/2016";
string originalFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
string expectedFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";
string d = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, originalFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                    .ToString(expectedFormat);

Console.WriteLine(d);
```

If you're not sure about the input's format, you can go with this safe side logic:

```
string FromDate = "12/13/2016";
string originalFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
string expectedFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";

DateTime convertedDate;
string expectedDate = null;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(FromDate, originalFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                    DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out convertedDate))
{
    expectedDate = convertedDate.ToString(expectedFormat);
}
else
{
    // handle format errors.
}

Console.WriteLine(expectedDate);
```

Comment: What happens if conversion failed?

Comment: @un-lucky the user said he has a date is a specified format. He didn't say that he has a unknown format that he must check if it is in some format or not. I wouldn't use `TryParse` if I'm 100% sure of the format.

Comment: But as a developer you should care about Exceptions

Comment: @un-lucky I do care about exception when they might occur. This is not the case for this question.

Comment: Well, I just say my opinion, anyway happy codding. I sincerly hope that waiting for Exception is not good

Comment: @user3185569 - We don't know what the input actually looks like. The OP didn't say. So good exception prevention would be in order here, IMHO.

Comment: @Enigmativity I added a safe-side approach.

Comment: FromDate = 10/07/2016
ToDate = 18/07/2016
string d = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
gives : 2016/10/07

string dd = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
gives : error

if i am using 
string d = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate).ToString("yyyy/dd/MM");
gives : 2016/07/10

string dd = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate).ToString("yyyy/dd/MM");
gives:error

Comment: @RahulSoni `Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate)` is wrong, you need to specify the format by using `ParseExact`. Follow the logic in the answer or edit your question and post the entire code.

Comment: @RahulSoni you can mark this answer as accepted if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime.TryParseExact` you will get it worked. Let `FromDate` be the date in the format `MM/dd/yyyy` and the required format string is `"yyyy/MM/dd"` consider the code:

```
string FromDateString ="07/18/2016";
string fromStringFormat= "MM/dd/yyyy";
DateTime FromDate;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(FromDateString, fromStringFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out FromDate))
{
   string requiredString= FromDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
   // Continue coding
}
else
{
  // Conversion failed
}
```

[Here is working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MTXayH)

Comment: From date is in dd/mm/yyyy format i just want in yyyy/mm/dd format but it shows error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @RahulSoni : which line Gives you the error? [Here is Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MTXayH)

Comment: FromDate = 10/07/2016
ToDate = 18/07/2016
string d = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
gives : 2016/10/07

string dd = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
gives : error

if i am using 
string d = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate).ToString("yyyy/dd/MM");
gives : 2016/07/10

string dd = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate).ToString("yyyy/dd/MM");
gives:error

Comment: is there any `Convert.ToDateTime` in my answer? you are still running your code? why don't you try the supplied answers?